# How to add the mulitple rows using column header with perl?

Tags: perl

I dumped the following table from linux command by using mysql queries.
My question is how to sum the values of every name  for column PEND AND RUN)using the Column header NAME.Here i had matched the every name and then calculated but i need to calculate according to the header name(i.e NAME).How can i do it?

My input file:

```
NAME            PRIO SUB     PEND RUN LALLOT  
adice_long      5    980766  199  107 - 

adice_ncsim     7    390188  2    6 

calibre         15   580     0    0   -
```

i tried the below code:

```
$DBH->do("USE $str1m;");

my $stmt = "select distinct * from queues ;";
my $sth = $DBH->prepare( $stmt );
$sth->execute() or print "Could not insert data";
while (my @columns = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    if($columns[2] =~ /adice/i)
    {
        $pend_count{adice} +=$columns[4];
        $run_count{adice} +=$columns[5]; 
    }
    elsif($columns[2] =~ /calibre/i)
    {
        $pend_count{calibre} +=$columns[4];
        $run_count{calibre} +=$columns[5]; 
    }   
    elsif($columns[2] =~ /vcs/i)
    {
        $pend_count{vcs} +=$columns[4];
        $run_count{vcs} +=$columns[5]; 
    }     
    elsif($columns[2] =~ /spectre/i)
    {
        $pend_count{spectre} +=$columns[4];  
        $run_count{spectre} +=$columns[5]; 
    }       
    elsif($columns[2] =~ /Incisive/i)
    {
        $pend_count{incisive} +=$columns[4];
        $run_count{incisive} +=$columns[5]; 
    }     

    else
    {
        $pend_count{others} +=$columns[4];
        $run_count{others} +=$columns[5]; 

    }
}
foreach $feature ( keys %pend_count)
{
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO job_status(time,job_type,pending_qty,running_qty) VALUES(\"$current_time\",\"$feature\",\"$pend_count{$feature}\",\"$run_count{$feature}\")";
     $sth = $DBH->prepare( $stmt );
    $sth->execute() or print "Could not insert data";
}
$sth->finish;
$DBH->disconnect();
```

Expected ouput:

Sum of the column 4 should be stored in one variable and sum of column 5 should stored in another different varible.The addition should be happened with the matching of all rows in column 1(i.e. NAME)

Comment: Could you please be more clear? What is your expected output?

Comment: Any expected output for brief detail?

Comment: My expected output should be sum of the column 4 and sum of column 5 should be stored in different variables@ssr1012

Comment: I guess, you want something like `$pend_count{adice} -> {PEND} += $columns[4]` and `$pend_count{adice} -> {RUN} += $columns[5]` for every name.

Comment: The  error message you throw when the query  fails is misleading. You say you can't insert when in fact your query is a select.

Comment: Can't you `select name, sum(pend), sum(run) from queues group by name`? And **let the DB to that thing** for you?

Comment: @PerlDuck It's hard to tell, but the OP may or may not want regex-based grouping.

Comment: @MattJacob Yes, indeed. I wonder why it was upvoted 3 times as of now. The input shown is a text file but the code does a DB select. We can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to sum the `pend` and `run` columns for each value of `name`. You can use a [hash of hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) where the top-level keys are the names and each value is a hash that contains keys for the columns you want to add up:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use DBI;

# set up in-memory database that should be close enough for this example
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:", undef, undef, {
    RaiseError => 1,
    PrintError => 0,
});

# create fake schema
$dbh->do(q{
    create table queues (
        name varchar(255),
        prio int,
        sub int,
        pend int,
        run int,
        lallot int
    )
});

# load fake data
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    insert into queues (name, prio, sub, pend, run)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
});

while (<DATA>) {
    $sth->execute(split);
}

# end of set-up code; on to the actual answer...
$sth = $dbh->prepare(q{select * from queues});
$sth->execute;

my %sums;

while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    for my $field (qw(pend run)) {
        $sums{$row->{name}}{$field} += $row->{$field};
    }
}

dd(\%sums);

__DATA__
adice_long      5    980766  199  107
adice_ncsim     7    390188  2    6
calibre         15   580     0    0
```

Output:

```
{
  adice_long  => { pend => 199, run => 107 },
  adice_ncsim => { pend => 2, run => 6 },
  calibre     => { pend => 0, run => 0 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just I think and know whether this will help you:

```
my (@columns,$columns4,$columns5) = ();
while(<DATA>)
{
    #Each row we are splitting by tab delimit
    @columns = split "\t", $_;

    #Checking the column fourth not equal to null
    if($columns[3] ne '')
    {
        #Store the value which is in column 4th
        $columns4 += $columns[3];
    }
    #Checking the column fifth not equal to null
    if($columns[4] ne '')
    {
        #Store the value which is in column 5th
        $columns5 += $columns[4];
    }
}

print "col4: $columns4\tcol5: $columns5\n";

__DATA__
NAME    PRIO    SUB PEND    RUN LALLOT  
adice_long  5   980766  199 107 - 
adice_ncsim 7   390188  2   6   
calibre 15  580 0   0   -
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is what OP expecting. Addition is not happening with matching of all row in column1.

Comment: `My expected output should be sum of the column 4 and sum of column 5 should be stored in different variables` this is what I did.

Comment: @serenesat: Could you please explain where addition is not happening.

Comment: Could you please explain the above code briefly@ssr1012

Comment: Doe this code works..Because am not getting the addition of values from your same code@ssr1012

Comment: col4:  col5: (No values are outputted).@ssr1012

Comment: `__DATA__` if you copy the above code please give the tab delimit instead of space. We are splitting the column by `tag delimit` only